# Get all Select elements on the page with value set to foo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several `<select>` inputs on my page.

Using jQuery, how can I get all `<select>` elements with the selected option equal to "foo"? (Keeping the result as a jquery set, so I can traverse from each element in it)

I've tried the following, but this always seems to return an empty array.
`$('option[selected][value="foo"]');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qvsgj/1/)) :

```
var sel = $('select').filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() == 'foo';
}).get();
```

Comment: awesome - assuming I can just drop .get() and keep it as a jquery set. Filter is really handy, I haven't used it before, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [];   
    $('select').each(function(index) {
      if(this.selectedIndex) {
        if(this[this.selectedIndex].value == 'foo') {
          data.push(this[this.selectedIndex]);
        }
      }
    }); 
    console.log(data);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G2szE/

Answer (score 0):

`$('select option[value="foo"][selected="selected"]').parent()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all **"select"** tags and their respective values in Javascript then use this code:

```js
var tag =document.querySelectorAll("select");
var values="";
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    values+= i+"="+tag[i].value+",";
}
alert(values);
```

Replace the number of values with `array.length`.